# How to use androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, preview

This's RecyclerView:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MJz1g.png)
and this is CardView:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M979b.png)
but design tab show me this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mIIrJ.png)
I wanna try to this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wfWct.png)
How I can fix it?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

As I checked on your question images, your RecyclerView item layout has taken full height of screen for each item. The problem is you set Cardview's layout_ height to "match_parent", that's why it takes full height.

Here you need to changes is,

```
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"> <!-- here you need to change wrap_content-->

...
...

</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```